# Python - set source port number with sockets

Tags: python, sockets, port

I'd like to send a specific UDP broadcast packet. Unfortunately, I need to send the UDP packets from a very specific port.

Let's say I broadcast via UDP "BLABLAH". The server will only answer if my incoming packet source port was 1444; if not, then the packet is discarded.

My broadcast socket setup looks like this:

```
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)

s.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, 1)
```

How can I then set the source port in Python?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to `bind` the socket to the specific port you want to send from. The `bind` method takes an address tuple, much like `connect`, though you can use the wildcard address. For example:

```
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 1444))
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `s.bind(('', port))`.